# Another word for sultry

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, offensive-language

I understand *sultry* means:

> 1. (of the air or weather) hot and humid.
> 2. (of a person, especially a woman) attractive in a way that suggests a passionate nature.

Lot of people associate *sultry* with definition 2.

In about a month (at the end of Summer 2015) I am leading an online study session (I am studying for Cisco certification and we are encouraged to teach what we know to deepen our understanding) that will be announced by Cisco Learning Network.

I like to pick catchy titles, but I doubt they will accept *sultry*, in the title, as in:

> *Bygone Sultry days of Summer: What the Port Remembers*

This session will actually review Cisco switching, including port security that includes "sticky" Mac address. Hence,the port of the Switch is remembering this Mac address ....

What is another word for *sultry* that is just as catchy, but is appropriate for an IT environment?

## Update

> sultry

is perfectly fine, will present this , thank you all!

Comment: Sultry works fine there. There is no connotation of 'passion' when mentioned with weather.

Comment: @Mitch if you were Cisco Learning Community Moderator you would be ok with  'sultry'?

Comment: @Mitch and instead of person remembering sultry days of summer we are talking about a port on a Cisco switch

Comment: @SohniMahiwal I'd like to echo Mitch that 'sultry' is fine there, and were I in the exalted, awe-inspiring position of being a Cisco Learning Community Moderator (whatever that is), I think I'd be fine with it just the same. I would, however, question what it is you're trying to get across by mentioning a "sultry summer* in the context of (computer) ports? If it's just to allude to the end of summer 2015, I think that's quite weak, and not enough to justify your title. Appearing contrived detracts from the cleverness of the title (such as it is).

Comment: @Deeoak it's not alluding to end of summer but rather 'sticky learning' of allowed Mac addresses to transmit frames into Switch port. My concern was whether 'sultry' wad risqué, not. The idea of the title actually popped into my head because it's hot and sultry in the East Coast and by the time I will be scheduled to lead this class it will be end of summer.

Comment: @Sohni Sultry is not at all risqué in the context of weather, and the risqué meaning to describe say a woman's eyes is pretty tame and old-fashioned (like say voluptuous). So it is perfectly fine. However, despite the use of 'sticky' in the definition, no native english speaker will associate sultry with sticky as in port address stickiness (which itself is a strained metaphor). It would be a weak pun only if you explained it. So if you want them to 'get' the connection, you'll have to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

**Muggy** is an adjective that describes hot and humid weather.

Definition (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muggy):

> muggy
>
> ```
>  adjective mug·gy \ˈmə-gē\
> ```
>
> : unpleasantly warm and humid

As the definition states, the word carries a negative connotation, though.

And frankly, I don't know if 'muggy' really fits your 'catchy' title.

I just came up with what I think is a *much* better word:

**Sweltering**

Definition (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sweltering):

> sweltering
>
> adjective
>
> 1. suffering oppressive heat.
> 2. characterized by oppressive heat; sultry.

"Bygone sweltering summer days" or "Sweltering summers past". Yes, I think those sound fine.

Comment: but I wish the summer to sound nostalgic ... how can someone forget something that gives fond memories. in this case, a port of a Cisco switch?

Comment: but I wish the summer to sound nostalgic ... how can someone forget something that gives fond memories. in this case, a port of a Cisco switch?

Comment: @SohniMahiwal As I wrote in the comments above, I think sultry is fine and not too risqué when used in this context. I presented alternatives (although sweltering is the best one, in my opinion) if you really want one. However, I would appreciate a clarification to the other question in my comments: what exactly are you trying to allude to by juxtaposing the season of summer with a computer port in the title?

Answer (score 0):

[Merriam-Webster online](http://i.word.com/idictionary/sticky) gives one definition of **sticky** as:

> unpleasantly warm and humid

And lists synonyms "humid, muggy, clammy".

You can have a "sticky summer day" meaning much the same as "humid" but it also contains a dual meaning (a pun) in terms of memory, c.f. a "sticky port". I think this would serve your purposes very well.